# Mongo mapreduce - use $dateToString on mapping stage

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework, doctrine-odm

I have simple collection of elements with following structure:

```
{
   _id: MongoId
   pvs: int
   day: IsoDate()
   uid: int
}
```

I'd like to use `MapReduce` to count pageviews for given user, grouped by certain date range (day/week/month, date `format` compatible).

What I'm stuck is how to reformat `IsoDate` in map function using `$dateToString` before emitting, so it emmits the format I want, like `%Y-%m-%d` or `%Y-%m` or `%Y-%m-%U`. 
When I'm calling it, I'm not getting reformatted date, but object with `format` and `date` fields.

Example:

```
function(){
    emit(
        {'$dateToString': {'format': "%Y-%m-%d", 'date': this.day}}, 
        this.pvs
    )}
```

will return

```
{
    "pvs" : 5
    "$dateToString" : {
        "format" : "%Y-%m-%d",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-07-13T08:27:29.000Z")
    }
}
```

I want to have this returned instead:

```
{
    "pvs": 5,
    "day": "2016-07-13"
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use the aggregation framework, where the `$dateToString` operator is readily available as well as efficient aggregation as compared to mapReduce?

Comment: @chridam unfortunately I can't - I'm using `doctrine mongo odm` which allows me to call only `mapReduce` (I know, stupid). And also I would like to solve this issue just to learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using mapReduce then you would have to create your own custom function that formats the date and call that in your map function:

```
dateToString = function(date){
    return date.getFullYear() + '-' (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
}

map = function() {
    emit(dateToString(this.day), this.pvs);
}
```

---

Better with the aggregation framework which runs "within" MongoDB in its C++ code hence more efficient that mapReduce which runs within a V8/spidermonkey (depending on your version) environment within the bundled JS console:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "uid": userId } },
    { 
        "$project": {
            "formattedDate": { 
                "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$day" } 
            },
            "pvs": 1
        }
    },
    {
         "$group": {
             "_id": "$formattedDate",
             "pvs": { "$sum": "$pvs" }
         }
    }
])
```

which in doctrine mongo odm you can run your pipeline using the `command` function as:

```
$connection = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getConnection();
$mongo = $connection->getMongo();
if (!$mongo) {
    $connection->connect();
    $mongo = $connection->getMongo();
}
$db = $mongo->selectDB('test_database');
$aggregate_results = $db ->command(array( 
    "aggregate" => "collectionName",
    "pipeline" => array( 
        array("$match" => array("uid"=>  userId )),
        array( 
            "$project" => array(
                "formattedDate" => array( 
                    "$dateToString" => array("format" => "%Y-%m-%d", "date"=>  "$day") 
                ),
                "pvs" =>  1
            )
        ),
        array(
             "$group" => array(
                 "_id" => "$formattedDate",
                 "pvs" => array("$sum" => "$pvs")
             )
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact I'm sad that something simple like date format is not available straight in `mapReduce`, but well, you provided working solution :)